# Adding a margin to the right of a very large table (overflowing the document)

Tags: html, css

I have a rather large table (a lot of data about products) that is larger than the available space on some screens, resulting in a horizontal scrolling of the page.

I want to add a bit of margin to the right of this table, so that it's not completely stuck against the right side of the window. (This is both for visual and practical reasons, since on smartphones the scrolling bars will appear over the content of the screen and therefore cause small readability issues.)

But the margin-right property seems to be ignored, even if the table is contained inside a div with padding in it.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Here's a small example of the problem:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #600;
  background: #eee;
}

.page {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #900;
  background: #ccc;
}

table {
  border: 5px solid #c00;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Test overflowing content</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  (body)

<div class="page">
  (.page)

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assign `margin and margin-right` to table tag.  `margin: 10px;` overwrite the `margin-right`. You can use `margin: 10px 100px 10px 10px;` for this. check updated snippet below

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #600;
  background: #eee;
}

.page {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #900;
  background: #ccc;
}

table {
  border: 5px solid #c00;
  background-color: #999;
  /*margin-right: 100px;*/
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Test overflowing content</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  (body)

<div class="page">
  (.page)

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake. I started my tests with margin-right 100px, and then added margin 10px and forgot to remove the 100px declaration. I've updated my question to remove it and avoid confusion. But this doesn't change the core of the question: there's no margin at the right of the table, be it 10px or 100px, as you can see in your own snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, added td in css:

```
body {
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 5px solid #600;
   background: #eee;
}

.page {
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 5px solid #900;
   background: #ccc;
}

table {
   border: 5px solid #c00;
   background-color: #999;
   /* margin: 10px;  No need for margin */
}
td{
   padding: 5px;
   word-break: break-word;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <title>Test overflowing content</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
    (body)

    <div class="page">
      (.page)

      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>_____________________________________</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                <td>_____________________________________</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                <td>_____________________________________</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question (adding a margin to the right of the table). There are always cases where the table might be too wide for the screen (e.g. with more columns, or images in cells).

Answer (score 0):

if you'd add a wrapper around that table, with overflow auto it'll fix the issue.

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #600;
  background: #eee;
}

.page {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #900;
  background: #ccc;
}

.page>div {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  border: 5px solid #c00;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">


  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>_____________________________________</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          <td>_____________________________________</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          <td>_____________________________________</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**

Try this code

I have added a media query as well, defining a fixed width for the table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Test overflowing content</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <style type="text/css">

    body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #600;
  background: #eee;

}

.page {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #900;
  background: #ccc;

}
.tableWrap{
    width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}


table {
  border: 5px solid #c00;
  background-color: #999;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin: 10px;

}
@media only screen and (max-width:960px){
    table{
        width: 800px;
    }
}

  </style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="page">

    <div class="tableWrap">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>_____________________________________</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `td{white-space: nowrap;}` if dont you dont want to break td element while resizing.